# Access child page controls from base page

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, inheritance, ajaxcontroltoolkit

Inside my ASP.NET application all my web content pages are derived from a base class which is derived from System.Web.UI.Page. Inside this base class I need to get some controls found in one derived class, SamplePage.aspx : BaseClass.cs. It I add the C# code below on Page Load inside SamplePage.aspx it finds the ContentPlaceHolderControl,

```
<asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
</asp:ContentPlaceHolder> /* defined in the master page */

/* inside SamplePage.aspx */
<ajaxtoolkit:tabcontainer runat="server" id="tabsmain" height="405px" Width="625px">
ContentPlaceHolder cph = (ContentPlaceHolder)this.Master.FindControl("ContentPlaceHolder1");
AjaxControlToolkit.TabContainer container = (AjaxControlToolkit.TabContainer)cph.FindControl("tabsmain");
```

whereas if I add it inside the base class I get this error:

> Content controls have to be top-level controls in a content page or a nested master page that references a master page.

Is there a way I can get the ContentPlaceHolder inside my base class too? And how can I access it?

Comment: There's no need for tags in titles. Please read http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/19190/147072 for more information.

Answer (score 0):

Here is complete sample code how you can access ContentPlaceHolder:

First master code (Site1.master):

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Site1.master.cs" Inherits="WebTesterInherit.Site1" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="head" runat="server">
    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">

        </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Now custom class that inherits from Page:

```
public class MyPage: System.Web.UI.Page
{

    public System.Web.UI.WebControls.ContentPlaceHolder GetMyContentPlaceHolder()
    {
        System.Web.UI.WebControls.ContentPlaceHolder holder = null;
        Site1 site = this.Master as Site1;
        if (site != null)
        {
            holder = site.FindControl("ContentPlaceHolder1") as System.Web.UI.WebControls.ContentPlaceHolder;
        }
        return holder;
    }
}
```

And finally page that inherits from MyPage (Default.aspx):

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site1.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebTesterInherit.Default" %>
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" runat="server">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
    <asp:Button ID="btnTest" runat="server" Text="Test" OnClick="btnTest_Click"/><br />
    <asp:Label ID="lblMessage" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
</asp:Content>
```

Code for Default.aspx:

```
public partial class Default : MyPage
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    protected void btnTest_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            System.Web.UI.WebControls.ContentPlaceHolder holder = base.GetMyContentPlaceHolder();
            lblMessage.Text = string.Format("Holder contains {0} control(s).", holder.Controls.Count);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            lblMessage.Text = string.Format("Error: {0}", ex.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've checked and you can find a control nested in `ContentPlaceHolder` from base class `OnLoad` method.

Sure it can be done... **but** remember that some pages may have **different** controls in theirs CPH. Are you sure that you are in the context of a page which actually has `tabsmain` control?

I think if you have to do such things you have some design problem. A mix of master page and downward `FindControl` (base class -> derived class) just doesn't feel right.

Answer (score 0):

Universal "search by id and type" method:

```
  protected T GetControlOfType<T>(Control root, string id) where T : Control {
    var stack = new Stack<Control>();
    stack.Push(root);
    while (stack.Count > 0) {
      var control = stack.Pop();
      var typedControl = control as T;
      if (typedControl != null && string.Compare(id, typedControl.ID, StringComparison.Ordinal) == 0) {
        return typedControl;
      }
      foreach (Control child in control.Controls) {
        stack.Push(child);
      }
    }
    return default(T);
  }
```

Usage:

```
   var control = GetControlOfType<MyControl>(Page, "MyControlServerID");
```